# Почему не ставятся запятые?

Tags: запятые

> И действие этих книг происходит среди какого-то студенистого
>   дня, лишенного красок и света среди вещей только названных, но не
>   увиденных самим автором.

Почему не стоят запятые перед "среди" и "только"?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Не думаю, что предложение из вопроса надо оформлять как цитату. Правильное предложение выглядит так: _И действие этих рассказов, повестей и романов происходит среди какого-то студенистого дня, лишенного красок и света, среди вещей только названных, но не увиденных автором и потому нам, читателям, не показанных_ (К. Г. Паустовский. Золотая роза). http://paustovskiy-lit.ru/paustovskiy/text/zolotaya-roza/roza_30.htm

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, мне казалось, что любое достаточно длинное предложение, которое выносится на суд экспертов, желательно форматировать как цитату. Вполне допускаю, что я не прав (т.к. на ресурсе я сравнительно недавно). Но разве существуют какие-то рекомендации не выделять такие предложения в вопросах в виде цитат?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Дело не в том. Вы мысль не уловили. Тут кто-то пропустил запятую, которая в оригинале присутствует. А вопрос именно о ней. Поэтому лучше не цитировать, чтобы не думали, что предложение правильное. Да и слова поменяны и концовка пропущена.

Answer (score 1):

"*лишенного красок и света*" - обособленный причастный оборот, после которого нужна запятая. И она стоит в оригинале:
http://www.klikin.ru/txt/goldrose.html

"*только названных*" - тоже причастный оборот. Он был бы обособленным, если перед "вещей" было бы другое определение:
*среди **важных** вещей, только названных, но не увиденных самим автором*.

Перед словом "дня" аж два определения (*какого-то студенистого*), поэтому последующий оборот обособляется.

Answer (score 0):

Определяемое слово и причастие, следующее за ним, отделяются лишь при наличии зависимых слов — причастного оборота. В приведённой цитате за исключением частицы *только*, от причастия не зависящей, таких слов нет.